# Wget says "No headers" receiving my HTTP response

Tags: http, http-headers, wget, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm running a server on a Raspberry Pi Pico W. I'd like the HTTP response to be consumable by Wget, cURL, Python Requests and browsers but I'm having trouble getting my HTTP response understood.

Chrome parses response headers, Firefox does not, cURL and Python Requests think there are no HTTP headers and close the connection, and Wget thinks headers are part of response body:

```cpp
WiFiServer server(80); // server on port 80
void loop(){
  WiFiClient wificlient = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients

  // If a new client connects,
  if (wificlient) {
    HttpClient client(wificlient, WiFi.localIP());
    net_time = millis();
    net_prev_time = net_time;

    while ((client.connected() || client.available()) && (!client.endOfBodyReached()) &&
           (net_time - net_prev_time <= net_timeout))
    {
      net_time = millis();
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read(); // read a byte
        Serial.write(c);
        httpbody += c;

        if (!client.available()) { // client is done, respond
          if (httpbody.indexOf("GET /api/last") == 0){
            Serial.println("Serving api request...");
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            client.println("Content-length: " + String(last_str.length()));
            client.println("Content-Disposition: inline");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println("");
            client.println(last_str);
            client.println("");
            break;
         }
       }
    }
...
}
```

`client` is an instance of `HttpClient` from `ArduinoHttpClient` library (via the arduino-pico core). Requesting with Wget it says:

> No headers, assuming HTTP/0.9

```bash
$ wget -O - http://10.0.0.27/api/last
--2023-02-24 22:09:34--  http://10.0.0.27/api/last
Connecting to 10.0.0.27:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 No headers, assuming HTTP/0.9
Length: unspecified
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-length:136
Content-Disposition: inline
Connection: close

3006, MHZTemp (C): 17, Temp (C): 22.40, Humidity (%): 30.00, Feels like (C): 21.48, CO2 (ppm): 653, Dust (pcs/283ml): 599.09, GPS Fix: 0
-
```

Using cURL I get:

> Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed

How should I format HTTP response correctly?

Comment: I guess `println` ends the line using a `\n`. HTTP requires `\r\n` line termination.

Comment: wireshark shows `\r\n` line termination in the packet between the headers.

Comment: Try with spaces after the colons. Not sure whether they are _required_ though.

Comment: this is not how you use ArduinoHttpClient. see the examples. but how do you make a web server with a client?

Comment: I've updated the question with more code. The client comes from server.available(), and I couldn't find an example in ArduinoHttpClient that included responding to a client, but the interface seems to be the same as WifiClient and other Client classes. Adding a space after the colon didn't change anything

Comment: the HTTPClient library can't be used this way. it is only intended to make a HTTP request and process a HTTP response. it is very different from WiFiClient in function.

Comment: @zeitoon are you limited to server software which are you using now or are you allowed to use another software to get desired result?

Comment: I'm using the Arduino-Pico core and `WiFi.h` which is generally compatible with the arduino wifi library

Comment: I think @Juraj was correct and I was misusing HttpClient, as removing it fixed the issue with wget and curl, as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting `WifiClient` instead of `HttpClient` solves the issue, and both wget and curl no longer complain of missing headers or HTTP/0.9. Looking at the traffic in wireshark, it appears that when WifiClient is responding it sends a TCP [PSH, ACK] packet with the HTTP status code whereas and then after wget or curl respond with a TCP [ACK] WifiClient responds with the rest of the data. `HttpClient` was not sending [PSH, ACK] (probably because it isn't meant to) and curl closes the connection in response to more data.

In the following is the wireshark traffic with different configurations. 10.0.0.27 is my Pico server and 10.0.0.193 is my desktop machine (the requestor).

**Requesting with curl and responding with `WifiClient` (expected behaviour):**
[image]

**Requesting with curl and responding with `HttpClient` (connection gets closed):**

[image]

So I think the PSH packet is the answer. `WifiClient` knows to send it while `HttpClient` isn't meant for this use and doesn't send it.